# populate multidimensional array based on data in table jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
 var $rows = $('.personalinfo').find("tr:not(:eq(0))");
        var valueToPush = {};
        $rows.each(function(){//find("td:not(:eq(" + tdIndex + "))");
            var $tds = $(this).find('td');
            var id = $tds.eq(0).text();
            var lastname = $tds.eq(1).text();
            var firstname = $tds.eq(2).text();
            var birthday = $tds.eq(3).text();
            var gender = $tds.eq(4).text();



            valueToPush["id"] = (id);
        });
        console.log(valueToPush);
```

This is how i get each value of my td in my table it is returning ok then i am putting the data in multidimensional array. Here i tried putting all the id in the array what i am expecting is

`{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}....`

but all i am getting is the last data and it is showing like this

`Object{id:"1"}`

What i want to get from this is something like this

`Table[{id:1,firstname:john,lastname:smith,birthday:010989,gender:male},{id:2,firstname:anna,lastname:cole,birthday:020478,gender:female}]`

I want it this way so i can later on use it in my sql statement so i can loop into it so i can save all data in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
valueToPush.push({
id: id,
firstname:firstname,
lastname:lastname,
birthday:birthday,
gender:gender
});
for (var i = 0; i < valueToPush.length; i++) {
    console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + valueToPush[i].id);
    console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + valueToPush[i].firstname);
    console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + valueToPush[i].lastname);
    console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + valueToPush[i].birthday);
    console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + valueToPush[i].gender);

}
```

Used this one it kind of work for now. I will check if i can get the value in the serverside. I am still hoping for more ideas

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
valueToPush["id"] = (id);
```

use

```
valueToPush[id] = (id); OR you can replace id with some unique key
```

because it considers "id" as string.